How to draw a thin black panel border around my plotted map using the argument panel.border in ggplot in R
Issue
I've created a map using shape files and point data from a .csv file, and I want to make my map more aesthetically pleasing by deleting the grid lines and draw a thin black panel border around my map using the argument theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.3) as if I was drawing a box around a plot using the package ggplot2 (please see the screen shot of my desired output).
When I create the panel border, the entire map is deleted and I can only see the panel border (please see the screenshot labelled 'Output' and the screenshot of my map without the panel.border argument).
If anyone can help, I would like to thank you!
R-Code
#Look at the CRS of the shape files 
st_crs(R_N_Islands)
st_crs(Red_N_Reefs)
st_crs(Map_Study_Area)

#First, turn .csv from regular a dataframe with lat/long coordinates into an sf
#object that has geometries using st_aas_sf(). THen reprogject that the match 
#proejection of the shapefiles with st_transform()
#Egypt Gulf of Suez S-650 TL / Red Belt
#EPSG:3355 with transformation: 15846
Ds_proj <- MyDf %>% 
                  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude_E_DD", "Latitude_N_DD"), crs = 4326) %>% 
                  st_transform(st_crs=c("R_N_Islands","Red_N_Reefs", "Map_Study_Area"))

Ds_proj

#Egypt Gulf of Suez S-650 TL / Red Belt
#EPSG:3355 with transformation: 15846

#Plot the shape files together using ggplot
Study_Area_Shp<-ggplot() + 
                      geom_sf(data = Map_Study_Area, color = "gray", fill = "grey") +
                      geom_sf(data = R_N_Islands, color = "green", fill = "green") +
                      geom_sf(data = Red_N_Reefs, color = "red", fill = "red") +
                      geom_sf(data = Ds_proj, color = "olivedrab", size = 0.5) + 
                      ggtitle("The Northern Reefs of The Red Sea") + 
                      coord_sf(xlim = c(33, 34.6), ylim = c(27, 28.2)) +
                      theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                      panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.3)) 

Output

Output without the panel.border argument

Desired Output


Try panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA, ...). The help page of theme says, for panel.border: "This should be used with fill = NA"

Thanks Edward, this really helped. Many thanks
